# Oracle SQL - Extracting text at various points of a string

Tags: string, oracle, plsql

I have the following text column in one of my datasets:

```
SYSID     SYSTEM_TEXT
123456    Customers level PP changed from 1062TTRZ to FH1342225.  Effective 04/27/2020.
123789    Customers level PP changed from FLF2 to CDAS2.  Effective 01/07/2019.
```

I need to write an expression that will extract the codes after the "from" as well as after teh to.

Desired output:

```
SYSID     FROM       TO
123456    1062TTRZ   FH1342225
123789    FLF2       CDAS2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` we can try matching the word which follows either `from` or `to`:

```
SELECT
    SYSID,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(SYSTEM_TEXT, 'from ([^ .]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS "FROM",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(SYSTEM_TEXT, 'to ([^ .]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)   AS "TO"
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks ! However it's including the  period in the "to" column. I'm assuming you'd just have to add a  replace expression?

Comment: @DepthOfField Then use the pattern `to ([^ .]+)` instead, q.v. the updated answer.